# Dirty test context since migrating from spring 4.0.x to 4.1.x

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to migrate an old applicaiton step by step, starting with migrating from spring 4.0 to 4.1.
While the documentation says that there are no breaking changes, it seems otherwise.

My integration test looks somewhat like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/com/a/KernelTestContext.xml"})
public class KernelTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration  {
        @Bean
            ...
        }
    }

    @Resource(name = "CsvResourceProcessingChannel")
    private MessageChannel csvResourceProcessingChannel;

    @Test()
    public void testIt() {
        ...
        csvResourceProcessingChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new ByteArrayResource(input.getBytes()))
            .setHeader(Headers.IMPORT_SOURCE, importSource1).setReplyChannel(testChannel)
            .setErrorChannel(testErrorChannel).build());
    }
}
```

The csvResourceProcessingChannel Bean accesses posts into the splitter bean CsvResourceSplitter, which is defined like this:

```
public class CsvResourceSplitter extends AbstractMessageSplitter {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CsvResourceSplitter.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private Map<Partner, CsvMappingStrategy> csvMappingMap;

    ...

    private void updateCsvMappings() {
        final Map<String, CsvMappingStrategy> mappingBeanMap = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(CsvMappingStrategy.class,
                false, true);
        csvMappingMap = Maps.newEnumMap(Partner.class);

        for (final CsvMappingStrategy csvMappingStrategy : mappingBeanMap.values()) {
            final CsvMappingStrategy previous = csvMappingMap.put(csvMappingStrategy.getPartner(),
                    csvMappingStrategy);
            Preconditions.checkArgument(previous == null, "More than one CsvMapping bean found for  partner: '%s",
                    csvMappingStrategy.getPartner());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem becomes noticeable with the final Preconditions check in updateCsvMappings:
While the test only defines one CsvMappingStrategy class, several more including duplicates are found since the upgrade from spring 4.0 to 4.1.
Due to the contents of mappingBeanMap during runtime I'm pretty sure that the context used here contains context elements used in CsvResourceSplitterTest, which looks somewhat like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration
public class CsvResourceSplitterTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public CsvResourceSplitter createCsvResourceSplitter() {
            return new CsvResourceSplitter();
        }

        @Bean
        public CsvMappingStrategy createTestMappingStrategy() {
            return new AbstractCsvMappingStrategy() {

                ...

            };
        }
        ...
    }

    @Autowired
    private CsvResourceSplitter splitter;

    ...

}
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong are appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell seeing only parts of classes and configs. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in `AbstractCsvMappingStrategy`'s constructor?

Comment: No, but I just tried CsvResourceSplitterTest.java to CsvResourceSplitterTest.java_. After this the critical place in the code passed without problems.
The strange thing is that I'm not even running the whole test suite, just KernelTest.java (Using Ctrl+F6 in NetBeans). I don't get why CsvResourceSplitterTest.java would be processed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful workaround for this was moving the CsvResourceSplitterTest context to a different profile:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("anonymous_profile")
public class CsvResourceSplitterTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Profile("anonymous_profile")
    @Configuration
    static class Config {
...
}
```